# AttributeError: type object 'CalculaVariaciones' has no attribute 'retornos_diarios'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I am learning composition in OOP. In the script I show below, I am trying to apply composition instead of inheritance. I don't quite understand the composition and with this script as an example I think I could do it more easily.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ImportaYahoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df_apple = pd.DataFrame({})
        self.apple_close = pd.DataFrame({})    
    
    def importar_cotizaciones (self):
        # Importar cotizaciones de Apple
        import yfinance
        name = 'AAPL'
        ticker = yfinance.Ticker(name)
        self.df_apple = ticker.history(interval="1d",start="2017-01-4",end="2021-04-10")
        self.apple_close = self.df_apple[["Close"]]

class CalculaVariaciones:
    
    def __init__(self, importar_yahoo):
        self.df_yahoo = importar_yahoo
        self.retornos_diarios = pd.DataFrame({})
        self.log_retornos_diarios = pd.DataFrame({})
        
    def calc_retornos_diarios(self):
        # Porcentaje de variación diaria
        self.retornos_diarios = self.df_yahoo.apple_close.pct_change()
        self.retornos_diarios.fillna(0, inplace=True)
        self.retornos_diarios.dropna(inplace = True)
    
    def calc_log_retornos_diarios(self):
        self.log_retornos_diarios = np.log(self.df_yahoo.retornos_diarios + 1)
        
class DibujaHistograma():  
    def __init__(self, CalculaVariaciones ):
        self.variaciones = CalculaVariaciones
        
    def mostrar_histograma (self):
        # Plot the histogram
        print("\n*******************************************************")        
        self.variaciones.retornos_diarios.hist(bins = 100, color='blue', figsize=(15, 8))
        plt.ylabel('Frecuencia')
        plt.xlabel('Retornos diarios')
        plt.title('Histograma de los retornos diarios')
        plt.show()        
        
importar_yahoo = ImportaYahoo()
importar_yahoo.importar_cotizaciones() 

calcula_variaciones = CalculaVariaciones (importar_yahoo)
calcula_variaciones.calc_retornos_diarios()
#calcula_variaciones.calc_log_retornos_diarios()

histograma = DibujaHistograma(CalculaVariaciones)
histograma.mostrar_histograma ()
```

It returns the following error

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
55
56 histograma = DibujaHistograma(CalculaVariaciones)
---> 57 histograma.mostrar_histograma ()
58
59

in mostrar_histograma(self)
41         # Plot the histogram
42         print("\n*******************************************************")
---> 43         self.variaciones.retornos_diarios.hist(bins = 100, color='blue', figsize=(15, 8))
44         plt.ylabel('Frecuencia')
45         plt.xlabel('Retornos diarios')

AttributeError: type object 'CalculaVariaciones' has no attribute 'retornos_diarios'

What am I doing wrong applying composition in this example? I will appreciate help.

Comment: That's because in `DibujaHistograma`, you're passing the class (`CalculaVariaciones`) and not its object (`calcula_variaciones`).

Comment: Thanks, I was actually passing the class and not the object. The correct thing is. def __init __ (self, calculate_variations):
         self.variations = calculate_variations

Comment: After this correction,  I get the error "AttributeError: type object 'CalculaVariaciones' has no attribute 'retornos_diarios'". Y don't     know why.

Comment: No, I meant when you were doing `histograma = DibujaHistograma(CalculaVariaciones)`. It should be `histograma = DibujaHistograma(calcula_variaciones)`. See if this works.

Comment: OK. Thanks, Now it works correctly. My mistake was, as you have indicated, that I had messed with the names of the class and the object.